# Select an id of the <a> tag and apply event on it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm generating a table from the Ajax function. In one of its column, I've an anchor field with a respective id. I want to apply an event on that anchor field clicked.

Here's what I'm doing.

```
$( "#26" ).on('click', 'a', function () {
        alert("jjjj")
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bpyn/)

Comment: The problem is `#26` is the anchro element so `$( "#26" ).on('click',  function () {
        alert("jjjj")
});` will do

Comment: No. its not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this way : Further reading [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click','#26', function () {
    alert("jjjj")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('[id^=26]').on('click', function(event, ui) {
     alert("jjjj");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Created dynamic html is not in correct format

```
 table_content +="<td><a href='#' id='"+j+"'>Test</a></td>"
```

You didn't closed anchor tag

then try

```
$( "#26" ).on('click', function () {
        alert("jjjj")
});
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2bpyn/6/

Answer (score 1):

You are missed to put end on anchor tag if you include it will work with follow code:

```
for(var j = 25;j<29;j++) {
        table_content +="<td><a href='#' id='"+j+"'> j </a></td>"
    }

$( "#26" ).on('click', function () {
    alert("jjjj");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bpyn/7/)